# Stronger Inequality than Holder Inequality

Tags: inequality

Is there an inequality that difference between two sides of it is less than Holder inequality?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A \ge B \ge 0$ is obtained from Holder (or any inequality you wish). Then $A \ge \frac12(A+B)$ holds, and is obviously sharper. You can in fact try out other means with similar results.